# R Write to Excel With Links

Tags: excel, r

I'm wondering how can I export an r dataframe to excel format file, with some links embeded. So that I can use R to create an xlsm file. When open xlsm file, I can click certain links and open other files or webpage.

I checked several R "Write-to-Excel" packages but can hardly find any one having such functions.

Anyone any idea?

Thx!

Comment: Related: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-r-htmltable-while-writing-to-a-csv-excel-file/37728/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xlsx` package has the function `addHyperlink`, for exactly this purpose.  `example(addHyperlink)` should get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much. I installed xlsx from CRAN. However, I found that there's no such function called addHyperlink (after requiring the package, I use tab tab to check that). Is it because I did not install the newest version of xlsx? Coz I found that version0.4.2 has just been released very recently.

Comment: Problem solved, I installed the latest version mannually. Now I have the function addHyperlink! Thanks again!

Comment: If my answer solves your problem then click the tick next to the question so that other people know that the question has been answered.

Comment: I need to add hyperlink to each row (whole column). E.g., column country code and link to explained.com/"COUNTRYCODE" to each row. how to do that?

Comment: @userJT Have you managed to solve your problem? I am looking at several columns that should be filled with links, so I would rather not do it cell by cell

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Openxlsx hyperlink output display in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975608/openxlsx-hyperlink-output-display-in-excel/74976120#74976120) ... I came up with three solutions to this using openxlsx

## 1. mark the url column as a hyperlink

```
library(openxlsx)

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  site_name = c("Zero Hedge", "Free Software Foundation"),
  site_url = c("https://www.zerohedge.com", "https://www.fsf.org")
)

# create and write workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "df_sheet")

class(df$site_url)<-"hyperlink" # mark as a hyperlink
writeData(wb,"df_sheet",df$site_url,startCol = which(colnames(df)=="site_url"), startRow = 2)

writeData(wb, "df_sheet", df) # overwrite the sheet

saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

## 2. apply the hyperlink to the site_name column

```
library(openxlsx)

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  site_name = c("Zero Hedge", "Free Software Foundation"),
  site_url = c("https://www.zerohedge.com", "https://www.fsf.org")
)

# create and write workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "df_sheet")

class(df$site_url)<-"hyperlink" # mark as a hyperlink
writeData(wb,"df_sheet",df$site_url,startCol = which(colnames(df)=="site_name"), startRow = 2)

class(df$site_url)<-"character" # change back to a character which is optional

writeData(wb, "df_sheet", df) # overwrite the sheet to get the new pretty name overlaying the hyperlink

saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

## 3. new column with the link applied to the names from site_name

```
library(openxlsx)

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  site_name = c("Zero Hedge", "Free Software Foundation"),
  site_url = c("https://www.zerohedge.com", "https://www.fsf.org")
)

df$pretty_link<-df$site_name #new column for pretty link

# create and write workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "df_sheet")

class(df$site_url)<-"hyperlink" # mark as a hyperlink
writeData(wb,"df_sheet",df$site_url,startCol = which(colnames(df)=="pretty_link"), startRow = 2)

class(df$site_url)<-"character" # change back to a character which is optional

writeData(wb, "df_sheet", df) # overwrite the sheet to get the new pretty name overlaying the hyperlink

saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern way is probably to use the `openxlsx` package. See the documentation for `?makeHyperlinkString` as follows:

```
x <- c("https://www.google.com", "https://www.google.com.au")
names(x) <- c("google", "google Aus")
class(x) <- "hyperlink"

writeData(wb, sheet = 1, x = x, startCol = 10)
```

Comment: I have a more complete `openxlsx` example posted as an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975608/openxlsx-hyperlink-output-display-in-excel/63093800#63093800

Answer (score 0):

The following approach can be considered with the RDCOMClient package. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_xlsx_File <- "D:/empty_Excel_File.xlsx"
path_xlsm_File <- "D:\\Excel_File_Mod.xlsm"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_xlsx_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

vector_Val <- c("https://google.com")
nb_Val <- length(vector_Val)

for(i in 1 : nb_Val)
{
  cell_Obj <- Sheets[[1]]$Cells(1, i)
  cell_Obj$Hyperlinks()$Add(cell_Obj, Address = vector_Val[i])
}

xlWbk$SaveAs(path_xlsm_File, 52) # save as .xlsm
xlWbk$Close()
xlApp$Quit()
```