# XLConnect hyperlinks

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I am creating a program that will generate a sample of a dataset for quality review.  The actual data will  be available on our intranet. This sample is output in an excel with a very specific user-friendly format.  I am wanting to use XLconnect to add hyperlinks to the excel document based on the sample.  I have been unable to find answers using several searches. I am hoping this is possible using XLconnect or similar package that will keep the format in excel. My code below adds just text, but not hyperlinks...

```
library(XLConnect)

Full_data_set = read.csv(paste(my.file.location, my.set, sep= "/"))

my.sample <- sample(Full_data_set$groupid, 50)
my.link <- paste("ourwebsite.org/group/" my.sample, sep = "")


wb <- loadWorkbook(filename = "my.file.location/Template2.xlsx",
                   create = TRUE)

writeWorksheet(wb, my.links, sheet= 1,   
               startRow=3, startCol=3,            
               header=FALSE)  
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: Add hyperlink currently appears as a wish on the xlconnect github page:  See:https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/issues/51

Comment: Appears the the package xlsx provides this capability. See:http://stackoverflow.com/q/9291868/2913622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

> setCellFormula()

```
library("XLConnect")

df <- data.frame(
      v1 = c("wiki", "google", "so"),
      v2 = c("https://www.wikipedia.org/",
             "https://www.google.com/",
             "http://stackoverflow.com/"),
      link = NA ,
      stringsAsFactors = F)

# Load workbook (create if not existing)
wb <- loadWorkbook("hlink_example.xlsx", create = TRUE)

# Create a sheet
createSheet(wb, name = "Sheet1")

# Create a named region on sheet
createName(wb, name = "Sheet1", formula = "Sheet1!$A$1")

# Write data set to the above defined named region
writeNamedRegion(wb, df, name = "Sheet1")

# Create an excel column ref. for formula and links in data frame
excelCol <- letters[which(names(df) == "v2")]

# Construct the input range & formula
formula  <- paste("HYPERLINK(",excelCol, 2:(nrow(df)+1),")", sep = "")

# Create the link column in data frame
df$link <- formula

# Set the cell formulas using index for rows/col
setCellFormula(wb, "Sheet1", 2:(nrow(df)+1), which(names(df) == "link"),
formula)

# Save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb)
```