# Openxlsx hyperlink output display in Excel

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am trying to take in a data frame an excel sheet that has two columns,

Column A contains names of stores 
Column B contains the URL of those stores.

I would like to take Column A and make it a clickable hyperlink so instead of plain text, it is a hyperlink to the store website.

I have attempted to use openxlsx package to generate the correct output.

I have attempted to use the following code snip.

```
x <- c("https://www.google.com", "https://www.google.com.au")
names(x) <- c("google", "google Aus")
class(x) <- "hyperlink"

writeData(wb, sheet = 1, x = x, startCol = 10)
```

which comes from this post of a similar nature. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48973469/11958444

My problem however is when I replace the appropriate parts of the code e.g.:

```
x <- df$b
names(x) <- df$a
class(x) <- "hyperlink"

writeData(wb, sheet = 1, x = x, startCol = 10)
```

instead of giving me a column of hyperlinks that has the store name as the output, it gives me the entire URL as the output. Is there something I am missing from my code?

I get an output that has a clickable link, but instead of the URL appearing with the name, it instead just prints out the URL.

Comment: To make this reproducible, could you share part of `df` with `head(dput(df))`?

Comment: Yes, I will get you a reprex. I need to make the dataset up. For the purposes of example, I altered what my data was. I will make a dummy set and get you a reprex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An approach using `openxlsx`:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  site_name = c("Zero Hedge", "Free Software Foundation"),
  site_url = c("https://www.zerohedge.com", "https://www.fsf.org")
)

# add new column that manually constructs Excel hyperlink formula
# note backslash is required for quotes to appear in Excel
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    excel_link = paste0(
      "HYPERLINK(\"",
      site_url,
      "\", \"",
      site_name,
      "\")"
    )
  )

# specify column as formula per openxlsx::writeFormula option #2
class(df$excel_link) <- "formula"

# create and write workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "df_sheet")
writeData(wb, "df_sheet", df)
saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: I like this but the link is not blue

Comment: Simple. Direct. No functions. Common packages. GLORIOUS. Thank you for posting this. Agree w B Rose that it doesn't look like a typical Excel hyperlink, but it works and is so much easier than other options in this thread or elsewhere online.

Answer (score 1):

I like the current answer but for me it leaves the hyperlink as black. Here are three alternative solutions that I came up with...

## 1. mark the url column as a hyperlink

```
library(openxlsx)

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  site_name = c("Zero Hedge", "Free Software Foundation"),
  site_url = c("https://www.zerohedge.com", "https://www.fsf.org")
)

# create and write workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "df_sheet")

class(df$site_url)<-"hyperlink" # mark as a hyperlink
writeData(wb,"df_sheet",df$site_url,startCol = which(colnames(df)=="site_url"), startRow = 2)

writeData(wb, "df_sheet", df) # overwrite the sheet

saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

## 2. apply the hyperlink to the site_name column

```
library(openxlsx)

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  site_name = c("Zero Hedge", "Free Software Foundation"),
  site_url = c("https://www.zerohedge.com", "https://www.fsf.org")
)

# create and write workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "df_sheet")

class(df$site_url)<-"hyperlink" # mark as a hyperlink
writeData(wb,"df_sheet",df$site_url,startCol = which(colnames(df)=="site_name"), startRow = 2)

class(df$site_url)<-"character" # change back to a character which is optional

writeData(wb, "df_sheet", df) # overwrite the sheet to get the new pretty name overlaying the hyperlink

saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

## 3. new column with the link applied to the names from site_name

```
library(openxlsx)

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  site_name = c("Zero Hedge", "Free Software Foundation"),
  site_url = c("https://www.zerohedge.com", "https://www.fsf.org")
)

df$pretty_link<-df$site_name #new column for pretty link

# create and write workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "df_sheet")

class(df$site_url)<-"hyperlink" # mark as a hyperlink
writeData(wb,"df_sheet",df$site_url,startCol = which(colnames(df)=="pretty_link"), startRow = 2)

class(df$site_url)<-"character" # change back to a character which is optional

writeData(wb, "df_sheet", df) # overwrite the sheet to get the new pretty name overlaying the hyperlink

saveWorkbook(wb, "wb.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```