# R: split a data.frame but keep classes

Tags: r, dataframe, class, split

I would like to split a dataframe into a list of dataframes and keep the classes of the variables.

```
# create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  id=c("1","2"),
  site_name = c("Zero Hedge", "Free Software Foundation"),
  site_url = c("https://www.zerohedge.com", "https://www.fsf.org")
)

# specify class for site_url 
class(df$site_url) <- "formula"

# split
dataframes <- split(df, df$id)
```

Now I wonder, why the splitted data changed the class:

```
class(dataframes[[1]]$site_url)
[1] "character"
```

**My questions:**

1. Why does that happen?
2. How can I split a dataframe into a list of dataframes and keep the classes of the variables?

Thank you for your help.

**Additional info:**

I came across this problem when I wanted to automatically write hyperlinks to excel files with R and `openxlsx`according to this very helpful post: [Openxlsx hyperlink output display in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975608/openxlsx-hyperlink-output-display-in-excel/63093800#63093800)

Comment: R doesn't really support a vector of formulas. For example `class(df$site_url[1])` just returns character. if you try to put them in a vector, R changes that into a list `class(c(a~b, c~b))`. So just assigning a class of "formula" to a vector is the problem. That's not really allowed and is what's really causing the error. `split` should work fine with proper vector types.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for your valuable comment. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/class.html tells me, that basically any value can be used as a class. Do I get it right that only the classes listed here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/BasicClasses.html are actually "allowed" and will work during data processing?

Comment: A class name can be any string you like. R doesn't really have protected class names nor does it check that the value you assign is actually valid. You can run `x <- 1:3;class(x) <- "data.frame"` but clearly that doesn't make sense and you run into problems if you try to use `x` as a `data.frame` since its a vector. If you want your object to behave correctly, you should only assign class names that are valid for the underlying object type. If you have a vector, then you should only use atomic class types. The second link is specifically for S4 classes in R which is a slightly different topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the attributes

```
dataframes2 <- lapply(dataframes, function(x) {
      attributes(x$site_name) <- attributes(df$site_name)
     x})
```

---

The issue is not related to `split` or methods of it.  In this case, it is `split.data.frame`. If we look at the source code, it is splitting based on the sequence of rows based on the grouping 'f' and then doing the extraction (`[`)

```
split.data.frame
function (x, f, drop = FALSE, ...) 
lapply(split(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...), 
    function(ind) x[ind, , drop = FALSE])
```

But, the `split.data.table` keeps the class

```
split(as.data.table(df), df$id) %>% str
#List of 2
# $ 1:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
# ..$ id       : chr "1"
# ..$ site_name: chr "Zero Hedge"
# ..$ site_url : 'formula' chr "https://www.zerohedge.com"
 # ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
# $ 2:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ id       : chr "2"
#  ..$ site_name: chr "Free Software Foundation"
#  ..$ site_url : 'formula' chr "https://www.fsf.org"
```

-checking the structure of the original data with the extracted rows data

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id       : chr  "1" "2"
 $ site_name: chr  "Zero Hedge" "Free Software Foundation"
 $ site_url : 'formula' chr  "https://www.zerohedge.com" "https://www.fsf.org" str(df[1,]) # with one row selected
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id       : chr "1"
 $ site_name: chr "Zero Hedge"
 $ site_url : chr "https://www.zerohedge.com" # lost attribute
str(df[1:2,]) # with more than one row
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id       : chr  "1" "2"
 $ site_name: chr  "Zero Hedge" "Free Software Foundation"
 $ site_url : chr  "https://www.zerohedge.com" "https://www.fsf.org" # lost attribute
```